# Node terminal is not working. What to do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I created an object with all the necessary information about the prices of goods (apple, mango etc), and then through the prompt and if / else I made two suggestions. First, a prompt window appears asking "Select an item to see the price or press the P key if the user wants to know the prices of the most expensive and cheapest item." If the user writes "apple" for example, the Browser displays the price at which the apple is written in the object. If the user presses the P key, another suggestion will appear in the browser with the prices of the most expensive and cheapest product.

Everything works fine in the browser, but not as it should in the node terminal. Whenever I want to type in the terminal, for example, the word "apple" to find out the price under which it is written in the object, it is not working well. When I press any key, the terminal simply repeats the sentence entered in prompt- "Would you like to know the price? Choose: apple, banana. Mango". So by clicking one button, the whole prompt text reappears in the terminal window, but if I keep typing the word and type "apple", it shows the price at which "apple" is written in the object.

How to make it so that when you press one button, the text that is written in the prompt does not begin to be written again?

Here is the whole code.

```
const salad = {

  apple: 1,

  orange: 2,

  banana: 0.8,

  mango: 1.6,

};

 

const prompt = require('prompt-sync')({ sigint: true });

const interestedIn = prompt(

  `Do you want to know the price? Choose: apple, orange, banana, mango.

If you want to know the highest and the lowest price of products in the list, press P.`

);

if (salad[interestedIn]) {

  console.log(`The price of this product is ${salad[interestedIn]} €.`);

} else {

  console.log(

    `The most expensive product is ${salad.orange} euros and the most expensive is ${salad.banana} euros. `

  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/heapwolf/prompt-sync/issues/25) with the module, which appears to have been abandoned by its author.

At the end of the thread for that issue is a link to a pull request which it said to fix the problem. You could use that Git repo as the source of `prompt-sync` instead of the usual NPM repository as a work around.

Alternatively, you could avoid passing multiline strings to `prompt`.

Alternatively, you could look for a replacement for `prompt-sync` that is actively supported.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it just by writing a shorter string line.